# npm install over mac book is saying "Please make sure you have the correct access rights..."

Tags: git, npm, bitbucket, npm-install

I have already set ssh key to mac book and same is updated to bitbucket also. But when I try to do npm install then it says `"Please make sure you have the correct access rights..."`

I tried setting ssh key with windows and there it works fine. This issue is coming only with Mac Book.

Anyone is having any pointers around it will be highly appreciated.

My error log is:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror    ssh://git@us.tools.publicis.sapient.com/ccap/rcp-frontend.git /Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-us-tools-publicis-sapient-com-ccap-rcp-frontend-git-431fc206: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@us.tools.publicis.sapient.com/ccap/rcp-frontend.git /Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-us-tools-publicis-sapient-com-ccap-rcp-frontend-git-431fc206: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@us.tools.publicis.sapient.com/ccap/rcp-frontend.git /Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-us-tools-publicis-sapient-com-ccap-rcp-frontend-git-431fc206: 
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@us.tools.publicis.sapient.com/ccap/rcp-frontend.git /Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-us-tools-publicis-sapient-com-ccap-rcp-frontend-git-431fc206: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@us.tools.publicis.sapient.com/ccap/rcp-frontend.git /Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-us-tools-publicis-sapient-com-ccap-rcp-frontend-git-431fc206: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@us.tools.publicis.sapient.com/ccap/rcp-frontend.git /Users/sunbansa0/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-us-tools-publicis-sapient-com-ccap-rcp-frontend-git-431fc206
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/sunbansa0/.npm
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're using macOS "Sierra" (10.12) or "High Sierra (10.13). Apple, in their wisdom, changed the behavior of their SSH client implementation for Sierra; as a result, the ssh-agent will not automatically add any keys. You can confirm this with `ssh-add -L`, which lists all keys currently known by the ssh-agent.

You can correct this by adding a section to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host us.tools.publicis.sapient.com
    IdentityFile /path/to/private/key
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

That adds the named key to ssh-agent the first time it's used. The key should then remain in the agent for as long as the agent is running.